# Calculate Mahalanobis distance using NumPy only

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for NumPy way of calculating Mahalanobis distance between two numpy arrays (x and y).
The following code can correctly calculate the same using cdist function of Scipy. Since this function calculates unnecessary matix in my case, I want more straight way of calculating it using NumPy only.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

x = np.array([[[1,2,3,4,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]],
              [[11,22,23,24,5],
               [25,26,27,28,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]]])
i,j,k = x.shape

xx = x.reshape(i,j*k).T


y = np.array([[[31,32,33,34,5],
               [35,36,37,38,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]],
              [[41,42,43,44,5],
               [45,46,47,48,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]]])


yy = y.reshape(i,j*k).T

results =  cdist(xx,yy,'mahalanobis')
results = np.diag(results)
print results



[ 2.28765854  2.75165028  2.75165028  2.75165028  0.          2.75165028
  2.75165028  2.75165028  2.75165028  0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.        ]
```

My trial:

```
VI = np.linalg.inv(np.cov(xx,yy))

print np.sqrt(np.dot(np.dot((xx-yy),VI),(xx-yy).T))
```

Could anybody correct this method?

Here is formula for it:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis.html#scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis

Comment: I wanted to calculate Mahalanobis distance between [1,11] and [31,41]; [2,22] and [32,42],...and so on.

Comment: The implementation in `scipy` is pure python code. You can just compare your approach to theirs.
See here for the calculation of the mahalanobis distance between two vectors: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/6a7327e8bb8248b2ea165180bc602edf1ab33dda/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L508-541
For the calculation of the distances for a matrix of observations you probably have to loop through each observation vector.

Comment: Yes, I tried to calculate from that source, but because of my little knowledge of Python, it's not yet complete. Could you have look at my trial.

Comment: Your approach only differs from spicy in yours including a transposed delta whereas the spicy source code does not transpose the delta in the second appearance...

Comment: @jkalden thinking it's a bug I have submitted report here http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-dev/2014-December/020301.html

Comment: @jkalden My trial based on numpy only approach is not working, could you solve it?

Comment: In the scipy source, `u` and `v` are one-dimensional arrays, so taking the transpose (in `ndarray` terms) makes no difference.

Comment: @xnx oho good to know, thnaks.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what you're trying to do here: ie why is your input a two-dimensional array? Are you trying to broadcast the Mahalanobis distance calculation over pairs of vectors?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to calculate Mahalanobis distance between [1,11] and [31,41]; [2,22] and [32,42],...and so on.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the construction of your covariance matrix. Try:

```
X = np.vstack([xx,yy])
V = np.cov(X.T)
VI = np.linalg.inv(V)
print np.diag(np.sqrt(np.dot(np.dot((xx-yy),VI),(xx-yy).T)))
```

Output:

```
[ 2.28765854  2.75165028  2.75165028  2.75165028  0.          2.75165028
  2.75165028  2.75165028  2.75165028  0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.        ]
```

To do this without the intermediate array implicitly created here, you might have to sacrifice a C loop for a Python one:

```
A = np.dot((xx-yy),VI)
B = (xx-yy).T
n = A.shape[0]
D = np.empty(n)
for i in range(n):
    D[i] = np.sqrt(np.sum(A[i] * B[:,i]))
```

EDIT: actually, with `np.einsum` voodoo you can remove the Python loop and speed it up a lot (on my system, from 84.3 µs to 2.9 µs):

```
D = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ji->i', A, B))
```

EDIT: As @Warren Weckesser points out, `einsum` can be used to do away with the intermediate `A` and `B` arrays too:

```
delta = xx - yy
D = np.sqrt(np.einsum('nj,jk,nk->n', delta, VI, delta))
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, upvoted. Actually, I wan to avoid the use of np.diag to reduce unnecessary computations for speeding up.

Comment: Thank you so much. May I know what do you mean by C loop?

Comment: The NumPy routines use compiled C code "under the hood", so they are a lot faster than the bytecode compiled Python loops (but you have to pre-define data types and array sizes). That's why the `einsum` solution in my most recent edit is so much faster than Python loop for `D`.

Comment: Please explain for me what np.einsum('ij,ji->i', A, B) does? Mainly the meaning of 'ij,ji->i'. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: `einsum` implements the [Einstein summation convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). The [NumPy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) have more detail but this call basically implements the matrix (dot) product by multiplying rows of A by columns of B but outputs (`->`) only those elements that lie on the diagonal of the result.

Comment: np.cov(X.T) produces covariance matix rather than covariance, does it really require covariance matrix rather than covariance only? If not, does not computing covariance only speed up the further processes?

Comment: You can use `einsum` for the full product: `delta = xx - yy; D = np.sqrt(np.einsum('nj,jk,nk->n', delta, VI, delta))`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Superb! Do you mind explaining little bit on your code?

Comment: Break it down into two steps: `p1 = einsum('nj,jk->nk', delta, VI)` is the same as `delta.dot(VI)`.  `p2 = einsum('nk,nk->n', p1, delta)` is the pairwise dot product of the rows of `p1` and `delta`.  Take a look at the `einsum` docstring for additional examples.

Answer (score 8):

Another simple solution which is just as fast as the einsum

```
e = xx-yy
X = np.vstack([xx,yy])
V = np.cov(X.T) 
p = np.linalg.inv(V)
D = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.dot(e,p) * e, axis = 1))
```