# Vectorizing (squared) mahalanobis distance in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, mahalanobis

I have X (n x d), Y (m x d), and positive-definite L (d x d). I want to calculate D where D_ij is (X_i - Y_i) * L * (X_i - Y_i).T. n and m are around 250; d is around 10^4.

I can use `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`, but this is very slow.

```
scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(X, Y, metric='mahalanobis', VI=L)
```

Looking at Dougal's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807843/vectorizing-code-to-calculate-squared-mahalanobis-distiance), I tried

```
    diff = X[np.newaxis, :, :] - Y[:, np.newaxis, :]
    D = np.einsum('jik,kl,jil->ij', diff, L, diff)
```

Which is also very slow.

Is there a more efficient way to vectorize this computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) and [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) helps in situations like these -

```
np.einsum('jil,jil->ij',np.tensordot(diff, L, axes=(2,0)), diff)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [26]: n,m,d = 30,40,50
    ...: X = np.random.rand(n,d)
    ...: L = np.random.rand(d,d)
    ...: Y = np.random.rand(m,d)
    ...: 

In [27]: diff = X[np.newaxis, :, :] - Y[:, np.newaxis, :]

In [28]: %timeit np.einsum('jik,kl,jil->ij', diff, L, diff)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.81 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit np.einsum('jil,jil->ij',np.tensordot(diff, L, axes=(2,0)), diff)
1000 loops, best of 3: 472 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed faster, although still too slow for what I want. I think I've found an workaround though.