# Vectorizing Mahalanobis distance - numpy

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-einsum, distance-matrix, mahalanobis

I have been looking at the answer from @Danita's answer ([Vectorizing code to calculate (squared) Mahalanobis Distiance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807843/vectorizing-code-to-calculate-squared-mahalanobis-distiance)), which uses `np.einsum` to calculate the squared Mahalanobis distance. In that case, the vectors are: `X` of shape `(m, n)`, `U` of shape `(k, n)`, and `T` of shape `(k, n, n)`, then we can write this as:

```
diff = X[np.newaxis, :, :] - U[:, np.newaxis, :]
D = np.einsum('jik,jkl,jil->ij', diff, T, diff)
```

What I would like to do is to add a dimension to `X` and `T`. Precisely in my case, `X` of shape `(m, n)`, `U` of shape `(l, k, n)`, and `T` of shape `(l, k, n, n)`. So the result D should be of shape `(l, m, k)`,

However, due to me not having fully understood `np.einsum`, I'm having nightmares with my case. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking about is [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). In the [`np.einsum` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) it says that broadcasting can be controlled using ellipsis. By adding `...` to your subscripts you can specify how you want it to broadcast the operation. Something like this should do what you want:

```py
diff = X[np.newaxis, :, :] - U[:, :, np.newaxis, :]
D = np.einsum('...jik,...jkl,...jil->...ij', diff, T, diff)
```

Note: You say you want to add the dimension to `X` and `T` in your question but you seem to add it to `U` and `T`. My answer assumes the latter. If that's wrong you'll have to switch the extra axis in `diff = ...`.